# :first-of-class workaround on pseudo elements not working

Tags: css

So.. I was looking for that `:first-of-class` workaround which is like this:

```
.myDiv {
    border: 1px solid red
}
.myDiv ~ .myDiv {
    border: none
}
```

And I have applied it to my own code which looks like this:

```
.chats > .replies .reply.self.seen:after {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.chats > .replies .reply.self.seen:after ~ .reply.self.seen:after {
    content: none;
}
```

And... the result is.. this:

[image]

So even if the rule is correctly applied in my opinion.. the `content` property is not overwriting the other one as you can see... I've tried with `!important` as well.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Figured it out. Though weird, I needed to remove the `:after` from the first selector in the second rule. Question updated.

Comment: You should add your resolution as the answer :) It does kind of make sense to remove the `:after` when you think about it...

Comment: Please rollback your update and add it as a self answer.

Comment: @StevenAnderson Was just editing my answer. Yea, it kind of makes sense. I was following the general rule of having both selectors identical.

Comment: @LGSon just did that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution to my problem as I had to remove the first `:after` from the second rule like the following:

```
.chats > .replies .reply.self.seen:after {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.chats > .replies .reply.self.seen ~ .reply.self.seen:after {
    content: none;
}
```